# use a style sheet in flex using no MXML

Tags: apache-flex, stylesheet

I have a few styles that I want to apply to a slider.

I'm aware of the MXML method of definig a mx:Style tag

```
<mx:Style>

        HSlider{

        }

        .SliderHighlightTrackSkin{

        }

        .SliderTrackSkin{

        }

        .SliderThumbSkin{

        }



    </mx:Style>
```

Instead of doing it this way I want to define all the styles in a style sheet. I then want to define my slider in a .as file (not an mxml file) and apply the stylesheet to it.

How I can I do this?

Something like the following is what I'm after

```
levelSlider= new VSlider()
            levelSlider.minimum=0;
            levelSlider.maximum=1;
            levelSlider.value=1;
            levelSlider.y=150
            levelSlider.styleName="sliderStyle.css"
            this.addChild(levelSlider)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the style sheet into your Flex application from the mxml file of `Application` class using `<mx:Style source="style.css"/>` You can add as many css files as needed.

Now if you have a `.customCSSClass{}` in the css file, you can apply that to your `vSlider` using `vSlider.styleName = "customCSSClass"`. Global selectors like `HSlider{}` will apply automatically.

Comment: cool. I didnt realize that defining styles in the main app mxml would filter to the rest of the app.

Thanks